# Japanese Tokenizer in JavaScript - Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, tokenize

Is there any way to use a tokenizer from either Python (such as MeCab or sudachi) or Java (like kuromoji) in Javascript? I am making a Chrome Extension that would give the top five most common words found in Japanese websites. I do not know a different way of parsing words from just characters. Right now I have been able to scrape only the Japanese text, so all I need to do is parse it now.

Answer (score 0):

The quality is not great, but Chrome (and maybe other browsers) do have built in Japanese tokenization. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61672829/how-does-chrome-decide-what-to-highlight-when-you-double-click-japanese-text/61673028#61673028) for details.